# How to read data embedded into the program's own ELF?

Tags: c, linux, linker, elf, embedded-resource

The `objcopy` tool makes it easy to embed arbitrary files into an ELF executable:

```
objcopy --add-section program.file1=file1.dat \
        --add-section program.file2=file2.dat \
        program program+files
```

It seems to me that it should be possible for the `program+files` to access `file1` and `file2` programmatically without opening and reading any external files. However, there seems to be no easy way to obtain this information from within the running program.

The files were added as named sections of the ELF executable. However, Linux only loads the segments described by the ELF program header table. The sections are never present in that set since they are not necessary for execution.

So while it is possible to obtain a pointer to the currently running program's ELF header, it is pointless since the sections were not loaded at all.

```c
uintptr_t address = getauxval(AT_PHDR) & -4096;
Elf64_Ehdr *elf = (Elf64_Ehdr *) address;

// dangling pointer, sections aren't loaded by the OS
Elf64_Shdr *sections = ((unsigned char *) elf) + elf->e_shoff;
```

My intention was to search the sections by name at runtime, find the ones prefixed by `program.` and compute pointers to them so that my code can use them like ordinary memory blocks.

I can't use predefined symbols for this because I want to support an arbitrary number of embedded files, including no embedded file at all. I need to look up these sections at runtime.

Linux will only load segments marked with `PT_LOAD`. Can these sections be placed in `PT_LOAD` segments somehow? `objcopy` does not seem to have the ability to edit the program header table and add new `PT_LOAD` segments. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: Have you considered instead just [linking with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158900/embedding-resources-in-executable-using-gcc) or using xxd?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes. That solution doesn't seem to work for my use case. I want my users to be able to add new data after the program has been compiled. Symbols would have to be linked into the executable at some point. It's a freestanding C application so I can't use `dlopen` to get at the symbols. If I could just get a new program header entry somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intention was to search the sections by name at runtime, find the ones prefixed by program. and compute pointers to them so that my code can use them like ordinary memory blocks.

You can find the `program` on disk (using `/proc/self/exe`), `mmap` it<sup>1</sup>, decode section headers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005322/50617)) and then compute pointers to sections of interest and use them as you wish.

> Can these sections be placed in PT_LOAD segments somehow?

No: that would require rebuilding parts of the executable which are not possible to rebuild without re-linking the entire program.

**Update:**

If you don't care all that much about memory usage of your program, you could modify the last `LOAD` segment to "cover" the *entire* `program+files`, and then you can skip the separate `mmap` -- the files would already be in memory.

You just need to increase the `.p_filesz` and `.p_memsz` such that `phdr.p_offset + phdr.p_filesz == file_size`.

The price is that you'll cause data that normally isn't loaded into memory (e.g. section header, debug sections (if any)) to occupy memory. But with demand paging, the price could be very small -- nothing should access these "extra" memory regions, and so nothing should cause them to be paged in.

P.S. I know of no standard utility that can update `.p_filesz` etc, but it's pretty easy to write such patcher in `C` or in `Python`.

---

<sup>1</sup> You don't have to `mmap` the entire `program`, just the part of it which contains desired section(s).

Comment: During my research into this I came across many of your answers, they were quite helpful so thank you. Is it possible to add a placeholder program header structure with a linker script?  That might allow adding data to the ELF and then editing the size and offset of the placeholder to cover it. [I just emailed the binutils mailing list](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/binutils/2023-November/130561.html) about this possibility but couldn't get it to work. Perhaps you will know the answer... For now I'm trying to work around it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76266176/512904).

Comment: @MatheusMoreira I revised the answer and take back the "No, you can't" part ;-)

Comment: For future readers: I created an [LLVM `lld` issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/72386) and [`mold` issue](https://github.com/rui314/mold/issues/1148) asking for a placeholder program header feature. Perhaps it will make it in.

Comment: `mold` has gained support for this. I've made progress but ran into new problems and ended up [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77510669/512904). Perhaps you'll know the answer to it too.